# Strange list assignment

Tags: list, python-3.x

i'm trying to make a program that will assign values of the list (lista) to another list (output), but the program is also changing values of 1st list.

```
def MAXJ(lista):
static = lista
output = lista
for i in range(len(lista)):
    for j in range(len(lista[i])):
        if(i != 0):
            output[i][j] = output[i][j] + lista[i-1][j]
            if(j != 0):
                output[i][j] = output[i][j] + lista[i-1][j-1]
            if(j != len(lista[i])):
                output[i][j] = output[i][j] + lista[i-1][j+1]
        if(i != len(lista)):
            output[i][j] = output[i][j] + lista[i+1][j]
            if(j != 0):
                output[i][j] = output[i][j] + lista[i+1][j-1]
            if(j != len(lista[i])):
                output[i][j] = output[i][j] + lista[i+1][j+1]
        if(j != 0):
            output[i][j] = output[i][j] + lista[i][j-1]
        if(j != len(lista[i])):
            output[i][j] = output[i][j] + lista[i][j+1]
        print("List:", lista, "\n","OutPut:", output)
MAXJ([[1, 2, 3, 2],[0, 0, 1, 2]])
```

That is the console

```
List: [[3, 2, 3, 2], [0, 0, 1, 2]] 
OutPut: [[3, 2, 3, 2], [0, 0, 1, 2]]
List: [[3, 9, 3, 2], [0, 0, 1, 2]] 
 OutPut: [[3, 9, 3, 2], [0, 0, 1, 2]]
List: [[3, 9, 17, 2], [0, 0, 1, 2]] 
 OutPut: [[3, 9, 17, 2], [0, 0, 1, 2]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Programs\Logia\Logia13\Etap3\Zadanie4.py", line 23, in <module>
MAXJ([[1, 2, 3, 2],[0, 0, 1, 2]])
  File "C:\Python34\Programs\Logia\Logia13\Etap3\Zadanie4.py", line 17, in MAXJ
    output[i][j] = output[i][j] + lista[i+1][j+1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't know why values of lista and output are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to note here:

- You should actually check if `i != len(lista) - 1`, `j != len(lista[i]) - 1`, because the last list index you can access is `len(list) - 1` (list indices starting at `0`). (Alternatively you can use `not i < len(lista)` and `not j < len(lista[i])`).
- By assigning `output = lista`, `output` and `lista` actually reference the same object. This means changing `output` also changes `lista`. What you want to do is a `deepcopy` using the `copy` module.

All in all:

```
import copy

def MAXJ(lista):
    static = lista
    output = copy.deepcopy(lista)
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        for j in range(len(lista[i])):
            if(i != 0):
                output[i][j] = output[i][j] + lista[i-1][j]
                if(j != 0):
                    output[i][j] = output[i][j] + lista[i-1][j-1]
                if(j != len(lista[i]) - 1):
                    output[i][j] = output[i][j] + lista[i-1][j+1]
            if(i != len(lista) - 1):
                output[i][j] = output[i][j] + lista[i+1][j]
                if(j != 0):
                    output[i][j] = output[i][j] + lista[i+1][j-1]
                if(j != len(lista[i]) - 1):
                    output[i][j] = output[i][j] + lista[i+1][j+1]
            if(j != 0):
                output[i][j] = output[i][j] + lista[i][j-1]
            if(j != len(lista[i]) - 1):
                output[i][j] = output[i][j] + lista[i][j+1]
            print("List:", lista, "\n","OutPut:", output, sep = '')
MAXJ([[1, 2, 3, 2],[0, 0, 1, 2]])
```